# Play 2.0 Scala Project Eclipse incorrectly adding Java files to project instead of Scala

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'm not sure Eclipse is doing this. Any ideas why this would happen? This also happens when trying to add a controller as well.

Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific about your configuration details here?

Comment: Followed the Eclipse configuration detailed here: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you installed the Scala plugin for eclipse? If not you can do this from the following location: http://scala-ide.org/download/current.html

After that, you should open the **Scala perspective in eclipse**

When adding new controllers, actually new classes, you just choose New Scala class from the context menu or new class from the menu.

Comment: I have the latest plugin installed for Eclipse. I have the Scala perspective set and it still adds Java files.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no eclipse plugin for play 2.0. So you can just add classes (scala or java it depends on what you choose).

You are saying that you are trying to add a controller : Maybe you are using play 1.x plugin for eclipse to create controllers but in this case it is normal that the plugin creates a java file because it is only designed for 1.x java version of play